# How does an electron beam move in XY mode?

Tags: oscilloscope, electron

I was recently observing some Lissajous figures on an analog scope in XY mode .
I was wondering how does the electron beam move . I know it should move from left to right but I find it difficult to imagine.

It's easy to think that the beam sweeps left to right whilst moving up and down while plotting say, a square wave . But how does it plot an ellipse or similar loop-like figures ?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 3):

Normally the horizontal (X) deflection is driven by a sawtooth wave, and the amount of deflection is determined by the voltage of the signal. This causes the beam to start at the left of the screen and move towards the right, and then snap back to the left when it has reached the rightmost point.

If we use a different arbitrary wave then we can cause it to move in a different manner; a triangle wave will move it back and forth, a sine wave will cause it to move slower towards the edges and faster near the center, and so on. By combining this with the vertical (Y) deflection we can cause complex shapes to be traced out on the screen.

Answer (score 2):

Normally the beam moves in constant horizontal speed from left to right while
being deflected in vertical direction by the voltage (e.g. from CH1) you are watching.

At the right end of the screen the beam is turned off and turned on again at the left edge of the screen.
The (sawtooth) voltage causing the horizontal movement is generated internally, inside the oscilloscope.

This is not the case in XY-mode.
Here deflections in both directions are caused by external sources,
e.g. horizontal by signal from CH1 and vertical by signal from CH2.
So in XY-mode the beam can move in any direction.
E.g. if CH1 is a sine signal and CH2 is a cosine signal (i.e. same frequency, phase difference = 90°)
the beam will move on an elliptical path.